# Php mysql insert current date into previously selected field

Tags: php, mysql

I've followed the advice that I've received here, and I started to experiment with coding.

I'm running a form that feeds info into a database with two tables.

It is the PHP script that should search through the database and do stuff.

```php
if (isset($_GET['form_submit'])) // check if card nr is in rom tabel
{
    $IDNUMBER = $_GET['idnumber'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from rom where Kort_nr=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $IDNUMBER);
    $stmt->execute();
    $val = $stmt->get_result();
    $row_count = $val->num_rows;
    if ($row_count > 0) //if card nr is found, then insert current date
    {
        $sql_insert_date = "INSERT INTO rom (Check_in)
                                VALUES(NOW())";
        if ($conn->query($sql_insert_date) === TRUE) {
            echo "Checked inn";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO rom (Kort_nr) //else just insert new record
                    VALUES ('$IDNUMBER')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully in rom tabel";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
```

I am trying to insert the current date, into the same line where the "card nr" was found.
All this does is insert a new line into the table with the current date.

My SQL syntax is the issue. I've tried with "while and do" but I get errors.

Also, is this a healthy way to code? I've just taken a small function and started building on it. Should I continue like this? Or is there an easier way I could achieve what I'm after.

Comment: YOu dont need insert query, you need update query

Comment: `UPDATE rom SET Check_in = NOW() where Kort_nr=?` ... bind the `IDNUMBER` and away you go.

Comment: Great, it works :)) I'm so happy, thanks for the help 
I just wrote Kort_nr=$IDNUMBER